# How do you drag and drop multiple UIImageViews on a UISlider how like trollbeads app does?

Tags: iphone, xcode, drag-and-drop, uiimageview, uislider

I am able to drag UIImageViews however, I am not sure how to go about dropping them onto a x coordinate UISlider.  As well as allowing them to do collision detecting, like how that app does.  Does anybody know how?